# How to darken image on EMAIL?

Tags: css

What's the best way to darken a background image in emails with CSS?
Eg I know usually you can use Filter etc, but I'm not sure if it works across all email providers

If using filter, this darkens the entire email including the 'overlay', and since absolute positioning isn't appropriate it's not a good solution

If using background linear gradient, it works great on many email apps, but some like hotmail won't recognise it since it uses 'shorthand' (background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('my_url')) -is there a way to not use shorthand for this?

Comment: Edit in a program like Photoshop?

Comment: I thought CSS works with emails just fine, filters included? And by "Filter" you mean https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty ?

Comment: @amn Maybe you're right, I can't seem to find that site where I read that filters sometimes don't work. ovokuro unfortunately not an option - there are thousands of images I want to use and it's not efficient to process them all

Comment: Shorthands are shorthands -- you don't need to use them. Every shorthand can be rewritten using individual properties instead. In fact, not only Hotmail may be having issues with shorthands, if it is Hotmail that is the culprit at all and not the user agent you are looking at the Hotmail emails on. I know several user agents that parse shorthands differently from each other, so there.

Answer (score 1):

**There are two common ways:**
1) [using CSS3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_filter&preval=brightness(200%25)):

```
.yourBackgroundImage {
    //halve image brightness
    filter:brightness(50%);
}
```

2) Using overlay:

```
.yourBackgroundImage {
    position: relative;
}
//yourBackgroundImageOverlay is a div inside youBackgroundImage
.yourBackgroundImageOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    // control overlay alpha by tweaking .5 in background color
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an email so I don't think I can use absolute positioning - eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403205/absolute-positioning-in-gmail-emails

Comment: Okay then, forget about position, try width and height 100% properties for inner div and same background-color.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it, @user6122500. Here you are given an answer with a working, straightforward CSS rule, that is designed to achieve exactly the effect you need, while falling back gracefully -- after all what is so paramount about forcing the recipient of the email to look at a toned down background image? It's *background* image, after all. The payload should be text content. Put the `filter: brightness(50%)` rule on the relevant element and hope for the best.